# Speed up SymPy equation solver

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a set of equations using the following python code (using SymPy of course):

```
def Solve(kp1, kp2):
    a, b, d, e, f = S('a b d e f'.split())
    equations = [
      Eq(a+b, 2.6),
      Eq(2*a + b + d + 2*f, 7),
      Eq(d + e, 2),
      Eq(a*e,kp2*b*d),
      Eq( ((b * (f**0.5))/a)*((a+b+d+e+f+13.16)**-0.5), kp1)
    ]
    return solve(equations)
```

The code solves the equations successfully but after approximately 35 seconds. The `Solve()` function is used inside an iterative block(about 2000 iterations) in another file so speed really matters to me.

Is there any way to speed up the solver? If not can you recommend another way to solve system of equations using python?

Comment: if speed is a factor switch over to numpy... http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

Comment: @ZJS That works only for linear equations as far as I know, Take a look at fourth and fifth equations in my code.

Comment: @Algo Can't you solve per hand first and then plug the variables into the solution?

Comment: @syntonym Come on guys! These equations are solved more than 2000 times that's originally the problem. (Would take forever by hand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to solve the equation one time. After that you will have equations of the form:

- a = f_1(kp1, kp2)
- b = f_2(kp1, kp2)
- ...

so you can simply compute a, ..., e in dependency of kp1 and kp2. For example solving the first, third and fourth equations gives:

- b: -a + 2.6
- e: 2.0*kp2*(5.0*a - 13.0)/(5.0*a*kp2 - 5.0*a - 13.0*kp2),
- d: 10.0*a/(-5.0*a*kp2 + 5.0*a + 13.0*kp2)

Solving all five equations on my pc is too slow, but if it gives you an expression you just have to plug in (substitute) the values for kp1 and kp2, you don't have to solve the equations again. For substitution take a look at the [sympy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution).

So your loop should look like:

```
solutions = sympy.solve(eqs, exclude=[kp1, kp2])
for data_kp1, data_kp2 in data:
    for key, eq in solutions:
        solution = eq.subs([(kp1, data_kp1), (kp2, data_kp2)])
        final_solutions.append("{key}={solution}".format(key=key, solution=solution))
```

Comment: kp1 and kp2 have different values in each iteration

Comment: That doesn't matter. You solve the equations symbolically, that means the equations will hold **for all** kp1 and kp2. For example you have the equations a+2 = b/2 and a+b=k, then you can solve for a and b in dependence of k: b = (k - 2) + (2/3) and a = [((k - 2) + (2/3)) /2] - 2. Then you only have to substitue k for your data point and you get b and a.

Comment: Okay that's a brilliant idea but when I tried to print the output of `solutions = sympy.solve(eqs, exclude=[kp1, kp2])` as in `print solutions` I got an empty list `[]`. I don't know how you managed to get b,e,d as an f(kp1, kp2) .. And thanks in advance

Comment: That means that either your equations are not solvable or sympy can't solve them. I just solved only the first, third and fourth equation. In your equations `kp1` isn't even mentioned, so thought you might have misstyped. I'm not sure why sympy can't solve eq1-5 easily, but you should be able to handle it manually. Second equation gives you `f = (7 - 2*a + b + d)/2`. The last equation is not linearly but you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistype error(corrected). Anyway I'm gonna try your approach again, However when I tried to solve a simple 3 linear equations with variables `(a, b, c)` using substitution to get `b` and `c` in terms of `a` I got the same empty list `[]`

Comment: Can you show the code? On a side note: You are probably not interested in the analytically solution, but only in the numerical? Then you can use a numerical solver, e.g. [sympy.nsolve](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve)

Comment: Will post the code later. I tried to implement a Newton-Raphson solver but I thought symbolic solver of SymPy would help.

Comment: Will also try `nsolve` and get back to you. Thanks for your help mate I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the 1st 4 linear equations for a,b,d,e. This generates two solutions. Substitute each of these into the 5th equation (in this form: `Eq(b**2*f, d**2*kp1**2*(a + b + 2*d + f + 13.16)))` to give two equations (e51 and e52). These two equations are nonlinear in f and, if you use unrad on them you will end up with 2 sixth-order polynomials in f -- which is likely why you get no solution since only quartics are exactly solvable in general. Call those two equations e51u, and e52u.

If you are interested in the real roots, you can use real_roots to give the roots to these polynomials *after* substituting in the desired values for kp1 and kp2 to leave only f as the unknown. For example,

```
>>> ans = solve(equations[:-1],a,b,d,e)
>>> l=equations[-1]  # modified as suggested
>>> l=l.lhs-l.rhs
>>> l
b**2*f - d**2*kp1**2*(a + b + 2*d + f + 13.16)
>>> e51=l.subs(ans[0]); e51u=unrad(e51)[0]
>>> e52=l.subs(ans[1]); e52u=unrad(e52)[0]
>>> import random
>>> for r1,r2 in [[random.random() for i in range(2)] for j in range(3)]:
...     print [i.n(2) for i in real_roots(e51u.subs(dict(kp1=r1,kp2=r2)))]
...     print [i.n(2) for i in real_roots(e52u.subs(dict(kp1=r1,kp2=r2)))]
...     print '^_r1,r2=',r1,r2
...     
[1.7, 2.9, 3.0, 8.2]
[1.7, 2.9, 3.0, 8.2]
^_r1,r2= 0.937748743197 0.134640776315
[1.3, 2.3, 4.7, 7.4]
[1.3, 2.3, 4.7, 7.4]
^_r1,r2= 0.490002815309 0.324553144174
[1.1, 2.1]
[1.1, 2.1]
^_r1,r2= 0.308803300429 0.595356213169
```

It appears that e51u and e52u both give the same solutions, so perhaps you only need to use one of them. And you should check the answers in the original equations to see which one(s) are true solutions:

```
>>> r1,r2
(0.30880330042869408, 0.59535621316941589)
>>> [e51.subs(dict(kp1=r1,kp2=r2,f=i)).n(2) for i in real_roots(e51u.subs(dict(kp1=r1,kp2=r2)))]
[1.0e-12, 13.]
```

So here you see that only the first solution (seen to be 1.1 from above) is actually a solution; 2.1 was a spurious solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your system of equations can be transformed to a polynomial system in terms of kp1 and kp2 as symbolic parameters. In this case it is advantageous to convert it to a polynomial system so that it can be *partially* solved in preparation for numerical solving for particular values of the parameters.

The technique her involves computing Groebner bases for which you will want to not have any floats in your equations so let's first make sure that we use exact rational numbers (e.g. use `sqrt` rather than `**0.5` and `Rational('2.6')` rather than 2.6):

```
In [20]: kp1, kp2 = symbols('kp1, kp2')

In [21]: a, b, d, e, f = symbols('a, b, d, e, f')

In [22]:     equations = [
    ...:       Eq(a+b, Rational('2.6')),
    ...:       Eq(2*a + b + d + 2*f, 7),
    ...:       Eq(d + e, 2),
    ...:       Eq(a*e,kp2*b*d),
    ...:       Eq( ((b * sqrt(f))/a)/sqrt((a+b+d+e+f+Rational('13.16'))), kp1)
    ...:     ]

In [23]: for eq in equations:
    ...:     pprint(eq)
    ...: 
a + b = 13/5
2⋅a + b + d + 2⋅f = 7
d + e = 2
a⋅e = b⋅d⋅kp₂
              b⋅√f                   
─────────────────────────────── = kp₁
      _________________________      
     ╱                     329       
a⋅  ╱  a + b + d + e + f + ───       
  ╲╱                        25
```

The final equation can be trivially transformed to a polynomial: multiply out the denominator and square both sides e.g.:

```
In [24]: den = denom(equations[-1].lhs)

In [25]: neweq = Eq((equations[-1].lhs*den)**2, (equations[-1].rhs*den)**2)

In [26]: neweq
Out[26]: 
 2      2    2 ⎛                    329⎞
b ⋅f = a ⋅kp₁ ⋅⎜a + b + d + e + f + ───⎟
               ⎝                     25⎠

In [27]: equations[-1] = neweq

In [28]: for eq in equations:
    ...:     pprint(eq)
    ...: 
a + b = 13/5
2⋅a + b + d + 2⋅f = 7
d + e = 2
a⋅e = b⋅d⋅kp₂
 2      2    2 ⎛                    329⎞
b ⋅f = a ⋅kp₁ ⋅⎜a + b + d + e + f + ───⎟
               ⎝                     25⎠
```

Now that we have a polynomial system we are ready to compute its Groebner basis. We will select `a, b, d, e, f` as the generators for the Groebner basis and leave `kp1` and `kp2` as part of the coefficient ring:

```
In [29]: basis = list(groebner(equations, [a, b, d, e, f]))
```

This now is a reduced system of equations for abdef with complicated looking coefficients that depend on kp1 and kp2. I'll show one of the equations as an example:

```
In [30]: basis[-1]
Out[30]: 
                                           ⎛       4    2          2    2          2    ⎞      ⎛       
 4 ⎛   4    2      2    2      2    ⎞    3 ⎜778⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂    399⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂    384⋅kp₁    1⎟    2 ⎜102481⋅
f ⋅⎝kp₁ ⋅kp₂  - kp₁ ⋅kp₂  - kp₁  + 1⎠ + f ⋅⎜───────────── - ───────────── - ──────── + ─⎟ + f ⋅⎜───────
                                           ⎝      25              25           25      5⎠      ⎝      6

   4    2            2    2         2               2      ⎞     ⎛             4    2           2    2 
kp₁ ⋅kp₂    15579⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂    13⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂   5148⋅kp₁     1 ⎟     ⎜  3799752⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂    8991⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂  
───────── + ─────────────── - ─────────── + ───────── + ───⎟ + f⋅⎜- ───────────────── - ────────────── 
25                500              5           125      100⎠     ⎝         3125              625       

          2                2⎞               4    2
  5772⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂   15984⋅kp₁ ⎟   23853456⋅kp₁ ⋅kp₂ 
- ───────────── - ──────────⎟ + ──────────────────
       125           625    ⎠         15625
```

Although these equations might look complicated they have a particular structure which means that once you have substituted values for kp1 and kp2 the final equation depends only on f and all other equations give symbols linearly in terms of f. This means that you can substitute your values and then use either sympy's `real_roots` or numpys `np.roots` to get either exact or approximate roots for `f`, substitute those into your other equations and solve a simple system of linear equations for the remaining unknowns. These are the only steps that would need to be done in the final loop and we can use lambdify to make them happen quickly. The final result then is

```
from sympy import *

# First solve the system as much as possible in terms of symbolic kp1, kp2
kp1, kp2 = symbols('kp1, kp2')

a, b, d, e, f = symbols('a, b, d, e, f')

# Don't use any floats (yet)
equations = [
    Eq(a+b, Rational('2.6')),
    Eq(2*a + b + d + 2*f, 7),
    Eq(d + e, 2),
    Eq(a*e,kp2*b*d),
    Eq( ((b * sqrt(f))/a)/sqrt((a+b+d+e+f+Rational('13.16'))), kp1)
]

# Convert to full polynomial system:
den = denom(equations[-1].lhs)
neweq = Eq((equations[-1].lhs*den)**2, (equations[-1].rhs*den)**2)
equations2 = equations[:-1] + [neweq]

# Compute the Groebner basis and split the linear equations for a, b, d, e
# from the polynomial equation for f
basis = list(groebner(equations2, [a, b, d, e, f]))
lineqs, eq_f = basis[:-1], basis[-1]

# Solve for a, b, d, e in terms of f, kp1 and kp2
[sol_abde] = linsolve(lineqs, [a, b, d, e])

# Use lambdify to be able to efficiently evaluate the solutions for a, b, d, e
sol_abde_lam = lambdify((f, kp1, kp2), sol_abde)

# Use lambdify to efficiently substitute kp1 and kp2 into the coefficients for eq_f
eq_f_lam = lambdify((kp1, kp2), Poly(eq_f, f).all_coeffs())


def solve_k(kp1val, kp2val):
    eq_f_coeffs = eq_f_lam(kp1val, kp2val)

    # Note that sympy's real_roots function is more accurate and does not need
    # a threshold. It is however slower than np.roots:
    #
    #    p_f = Poly(eq_f_coeffs, f)
    #    f_vals = real_roots(p_f)                  # exact (RootOf)
    #    f_vals = [r.n() for r in real_roots(p_f)] # approximate
    #
    f_vals = np.roots(eq_f_coeffs)
    f_vals = f_vals.real[abs(f_vals.imag) < 1e-10] # arbitrary threshold

    sols = []
    for f_i in f_vals:
        abde_vals = sol_abde_lam(f_i, kp1val, kp2val)
        sol = {f: f_i}
        sol.update(zip([a,b,d,e], abde_vals))
        sols.append(sol)

    return sols
```

Now you can generate the solutions for particular values of `kp1` and `kp2` in around 1 millisecond:

```
In [40]: %time solve_k(2.1, 3.8)
CPU times: user 1.59 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.59 ms
Wall time: 1.51 ms
Out[40]: 
[{a: 49.77432869943, b: -47.174328699430006, d: -0.7687860254920669, e: 2.768786025492067, f: -22.30277
1336968966}, {a: 3.4616794447024692, b: -0.8616794447024684, d: 36.964491584342106, e: -34.964491584342
11, f: -18.01308551452229}, {a: -0.5231222050642267, b: 3.1231222050642273, d: -0.0922228459726158, e: 
2.092222845972616, f: 2.507672525518422}, {a: 0.34146680496125464, b: 2.258533195038746, d: 0.076528664
56901455, e: 1.9234713354309858, f: 1.9910022652348665}]
```

Caveats: the method above will work in most cases for a polynomial system like this although there are cases where the Groebner basis won't fully separate without the additional use of a splitting variable. Basically just introduce a new variable say `t` and a random equation like `t = a + 2*b + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f`. Then make `t` the last symbol for the Groebner basis and compute `t` instead of `f` with `np.roots`. Also in some cases computing the Groebner basis can be extremely slow but remember that it only *ever* needs to be computed once (you could save the result in a file if needed).

Another caveat is that squaring to transform into a polynomial system will introduce spurious solutions that don't satisfy the original radical equations. You can check by substituting into the original system. In this case only the last equation matters:

```
In [41]: sols =  solve_k(2.1, 3.8)

In [42]: equations[-1].subs(sols[0])
Out[42]: -2.10000000000001 = kp₁

In [43]: equations[-1].subs(sols[1])
Out[43]: -2.10000000000006 = kp₁

In [44]: equations[-1].subs(sols[2])
Out[44]: -2.09999999999995 = kp₁

In [45]: equations[-1].subs(sols[3])
Out[45]: 2.09999999999993 = kp₁
```

So we see that of the 4 solutions returned only the last is correct because it (approximately) satisfies `kp1 = 2.1` which was the value passed in. This means a bit of post-processing is needed to get the solutions that you actually want.